# Testing bignum arithmetic

Tags: testing, math, bignum

I'm writing an arbitrary precision rational number package, which I'll need to test for correctness and efficiency. Of course I could put together an ad hoc set of tests myself, but since I'm far from the first to be doing this, I figure it's worth asking: can anyone recommend an existing set of tests I could use?

**Edit:** I ended up writing a test routine that each time around the loop, generates three random numbers and verifies that various arithmetic identities hold. It's found several bugs in the numeric code so far. Here's the actual code:

```
for (i = 0;; i++)
{
    mem = memlo;
    printf(fmtw "\r", i);

    a = rndnum();
    b = rndnum();
    c = rndnum();

    // Equality
    test(eq(a, a));
    test(!eq(a, b) || !eq(b, c) || eq(a, c));

    // Addition
    test(eq(add(add(a, b), c), add(a, add(b, c))));
    test(eq(add(a, b), add(b, a)));
    test(eq(add(a, zero), a));

    // Subtraction
    test(eq(sub(add(a, b), b), a));
    test(sub(a, a) == zero);
    test(eq(sub(a, b), add(a, sub(zero, b))));

    // Multiplication
    test(eq(mul(mul(a, b), c), mul(a, mul(b, c))));
    test(eq(mul(a, b), mul(b, a)));
    test(eq(mul(a, one), a));
    test(eq(mul(a, add(b, c)), add(mul(a, b), mul(a, c))));

    // Division
    test(b == zero || eq(div_(mul(a, b), b), a));
    test(a == zero || div_(a, a) == (one));
    test(b == zero || eq(div_(a, b), mul(a, div_(one, b))));
    test(c == zero
        || eq(div_(sub(a, b), c), sub(div_(a, c), div_(b, c))));

    // I/O
    test(eq(a, roundtrip(a)));
}
```

Comment: One things about testing with random numbers is that you'll want to set a seed if you want the tests to be reproducible. It's a real bummer to get a failure report and then not be able to reproduce the run because you don't know the seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at unit tests of open source rational implementations. Ruby's `rational` supports arbitrary precision, though only a few tests in `test/ruby/test_rational2.rb` push past 32 bits. For instance:

```
assert_equal(Rational(2305842940494218450, 1152921470247108503),
             Rational(1073741789, 1073741827) + Rational(1073741827, 1073741789))
```

Similarly for Python's test_fractions.py:

```
 self.assertTypedEquals(10**23, 10**22 // F(1, 10))
```

[GNU MPL](http://gmplib.org/) has some rational unit tests mostly based on random numbers.

The [IMath](http://spinning-yarns.org/michael/sw/imath/) package has a good set of tests, such as:

```
qadd:-14,9/2,-20:-19/2
qadd:-60,=1,43/2:-120
qadd:375/18696391582109365451,-131/32949770573031503434,166/56750232802998421883:9906936667630486913669/616041813174061083543307811398267458734
qadd:615/80348516296708248277,=1,=2:1230/80348516296708248277
```

It's not obvious to me how other open source rational bignum packages like Scheme and Sage are tested, but if you're motivated their tests should exist somewhere.